# What Codeigniter directories I should provide to composer for creating technical Documentation?

Tags: codeigniter, composer-php, phpdoc

I'm Using [PhpDocumentor](https://www.phpdoc.org/) to create a technical documentation for a Codeigniter project.

I know how to create the documentation for a simple PHP project, But creating the documentation for a CodeIgniter project is quite difficult, as I don't know where should I put my vendor folder and which directory (like application or controllers) I should provide to the composer.

I didn't find any solution or tutorial or article for integrating the PHPDOC with CODEIGNITER.
So a little help or a link to the solution will be highly appreciated.

Or can someone please recommend a tool that's better than phpdoc and can easily integrate with CodeIgniter. It'll be very helpful

Comment: you can create vedor folder inside application folder

Answer (score 0):

For documenting an application, there are usually two approaches, and some folks do both separately.

For the user/consumer, only the usable API would show up in the docs. That requires you to be very specific about which few files/classes to include. Some use the `@api` tag for noting the classes and methods, but I'm not sure which doc generators recognize that tag.

For developer docs, you'd include everything from your own code, but most people do not include dependencies from `vendor/`.  But if you want really comprehensive docs, so that any dependency class is also in the docs, you would include `vendor/`. In this case, where you located that folder doesn't really matter, as long as you do tell the doc generator to include it.